# Show that this linear operator is not continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis

This is a question of my last exam in Functional Analysis of my graduation:

> Consider that norm: $|f|=\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)$ where $f\in C^0([0,1])$. Show that the linear operator $f(1-x)\in C^0([0,1])$ is not continuous.

**MY ATTEMPT**

I show that this operator is bounded with norm 1. So the operator is continuous and the teacher give me 0 in this question

**MY FRIENDS ATTEMPT**

Talking with my friends, they say that:
"This norm is more "refined" that the L1 norm, so the operator is limited."

**MY TEACHER BLA BLA BLA**
He say the operator is NOT limited but don't say the demonstration

I believe that all is wrong but I don't know how to show this...

Comment: Is the operator $f(1-x)$ or $f(x)\times(1-x)$?

Comment: Is the operator $f(1-x)$, @ellya.

Comment: Compute the relevant quantities for $f(x)=(1-x)^n$.

Comment: $f(x)=1/x \notin C^0([0,1])$, @Arthur

Comment: @felipe: "$f(1-x) $"  is not really notation that expresses a linear operator. What you want to say is that your operator maps $f\mapsto f\circ g$, where $g(x)=1-x$. Also, it is not "limited" but "bounded".

Answer (score 3):

Write $T$ for your operator. If you let $f_n(x)=n(1-x)^n$, then $|f_n|\to0$, while $|Tf_n|\to1$.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 relevant spaces here. You need to be careful where each element is and what the relevant notion of convergence is.

1. The interval $[0,1]$
2. The Banach space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions on the interval. This space has the norm $\|f\|=\int_0^1 x^2 |f(x)|dx$
3. The vector space $V$ of all automorphisms $C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ with the operator norm. That is to say $\|A\|_{op} = \sup \{\|Af\| \colon \|f\|=1\}$.

Breaking down the definition of the operator norm we get. . .

$\displaystyle \|A\|_{op} = \sup \Big \{ \Big \|\int_0^1 x^2 |Af(x)|dx \Big\| \colon \int_0^1 x^2 |f(x)|dx = 1\}$.

What you want to prove is this value is undefined (infinite) for your given operator.

Your given operator is an element of $V$. That is to say a automorphism of $C[0,1]$ given by $Af(x) = f(1-x)$.

One strategy is to find a sequence of functions $f_n$ such that the RHS of the $:$ remains at $1$ while the LHS increases to infinity.